# Issue with wcf streaming on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I am trying to stream through WCF. It works on standalone but hosted on IIS I receive an exception at the upload method. I set to True the debug option on Web.cofig to get a better understanding but all I get is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The handle is invalid.

```
if (client.isItOpen())
{
   client.fileName(fileName);
   FileStream instream1 = File.OpenRead(filePath);                
   bool result1 = client.UploadStream(instream1);
   if (result1)
```

Since the isItOpen() returns true there is communication with the service but at the UploadStream is the exception. Are there certain options I need to set at the IIS to make it work? I remeber I was changing the upload limit but nothing more. The file I am upload is small, only a couple of KB.

Client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://IP_HERE/SyncWCF/SyncService.svc/ep1"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ISyncService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>

if (client.isItOpen())
        {
            client.fileName(fileName);
            FileStream instream1 = File.OpenRead(filePath);                
            bool result1 = client.UploadStream(instream1);
            if (result1)
            {
                StatusTextBox.AppendText("Done!" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            instream1.Close();
        }
        client.Close();
```

Service:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="SyncWCF.SyncService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/SyncService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
    <endpoint address="ep1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SyncWCF.ISyncService"/>
    <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost/SyncService/mex -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <!-- an example basicHttpBinding using streaming -->
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

```
 public bool UploadStream(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        //this implementation places the uploaded file
        //in the current directory and calls it "uploadedfile"
        //with no file extension
        string filePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, FileName);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Saving to file {0}", filePath);
            FileStream outstream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            //read from the input stream in 4K chunks
            //and save to output stream
            const int bufferLen = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1); Console.WriteLine(buffer);
                outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            outstream.Close();
            stream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} saved", filePath);

            FileName = null;
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: 1) Make sure the path is correct. 2) make sure the account that the service is running under has access to the file.  3) put a try/catch around  FileStream instream1 = File.OpenRead(filePath); so you can catch the actual exception.

Comment: What binding are you using? IIS does not work out-of-the-box with `net.tcp`.

Comment: It's basicHttpBinding.

Comment: Are you using `IIS Express` or `Local IIS` ? Are you running it from command-line or from Visual Studio ? From VS, you may need to run it as `Administrator`. From command-line you need to deploy it to local IIS first.

Comment: It's local IIS. I published it and added to IIS. It's annoying that the exception message doesn't help at all. Even with try catch.

Comment: Because it is `Local IIS` your service is probably trying to write to `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv`, which most likely won't be allowed. In your service implementation, replace `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` with some other folder like `C:\Users\Public\Documents` that you have write access.

Comment: I remember "playing" with examples and being able to write to inetsrv. I changed it. Still nothing.

Comment: I opened the inetsrv and the files I sent were there but they were empty.

Comment: These files may be locked from a previous unsuccessful execution where the stream was not properly closed. Cleanup your folder before any new execution. Just wondering: why don't you put a break point in your service and see exactly what is going on ?

Comment: FYI, people won't see your comments unless you start it with `@someusername`

Comment: Do you really need this: `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);` ?

Comment: @jstreet I removed every `Console` line and it works! I guess `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);` was to blame. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Yes you can.... i could post an answer and you could accept it...:O)

Comment: @jstreet Sure! Go ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.ServiceModel.FaultException - The handle is invalid` is caused by this line in your service implementation:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
```

Just remove it.